# Two different cells in a Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

This is my pList. Root Array name is mainList:

[image]

I want to see @"BankaAdi" and @"Urun"(in taksitler array) in my tableview.

I think I should create second Cell for writing @"Urun" because my main cell only writes @"BankaAdi" with this code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = 
    [[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"BankaAdi"];
```

How can I see my @"Urun" strings in my tableview?

Comment: still no answer !! someone help me please..

Comment: where is everyone ???

Comment: So you want to have a table with two sections? am i right?

Comment: @leonthegosu, Putting the `ios` or `objective-c` tag on your questions will improve their visibility and should generate quicker responses.

Comment: thank you for suggestion. I added Objective-C tag.

Comment: still no answer what is the problem why people hasnt answered my question yet ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, what you need is a table with two different sections. So in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you need to setup your cell according to the section.

Here's how it should look like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section == 1)
  {
     // for first part
     return array1.length;
  }
  else
  {
     // for second part
     return array2.length;
  }
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 2;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell cell = nil;
  if (indexPath.section == 0)
  {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Adi"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f TL",[[[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"dAdi"] floatValue]];
  }
  else
  {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Adi"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f TL",[[[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"dAdi"] floatValue]];
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: First of all Thank you for answer...I tried to explain my question again.So please look my question.